# Laravel, how to append new connection in config/database.php file?

Tags: php, laravel

My goal is to append/generate new connection in config/database.php file right after I created new database trough `DB::statement`

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405757/dynamically-edit-config-database-php-file-in-laravel), but the problem is that it is pre-defined in config/database.php.

**web.php (route)**

```
Route::get('test', function(){

    DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE testDB;'); //create database

    //append/generate new connection in config/database.php logic here

    DB::connection('testDB')->table('some_tables'); //would like to connect this newly created database but config/database.php havent setup yet
});
```

**config/database.php**

Would like to see it is edited on the fly like this below. But I don't have any idea how to do it without manually editing the actual file. Assume the driver, host, port, username and password are the same.

```
'testDB' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => '1234',
        'database'  => 'testDB',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
    ],
```

Comment: Can you clarify - should the new database connection be permanently saved in `config/database.php`?

Comment: yes, i would like to permanently save it

Comment: How often are new databases created? How many do you anticipate winding up with?

Comment: depends on the admin...maybe 10 database/month...or maybe more

Comment: You may want to consider other approaches, like a multi-tenant database structure.

Comment: how about if the admin like to create 1 database/month?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE testDB;'); //create database

    config(['database.testDB' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => '1234',
        'database'  => 'testDB',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
    ]]);

    DB::connection('testDB')->table('some_tables'); //would like to connect this newly created database but config/database.php havent setup yet
});
```

Comment: Note, however, that this won't persist - it doesn't update the config file. Subsequent pageviews won't have the new connection.

Comment: hmm...it does not update the database.php file...it stay the same...btw, you have some typo there should be closing `]]);`

Comment: Right, sorry about that, fixed the typo. Good point @ceejayoz, this doesn't actually write to database.php, it just sets a new config option for the duration of the process.